# 10.04 server won't boot off latest kernel

Tags: grub2, kernel, boot-partition

I'm maintaining a 10.04 server that is still booting off of the 2.6.32-28 kernel even though a bunch of later kernels are available. My best guess is that the immediately following version was purged from dpkg.

When I run:

```
dpkg --list 'linux-image*'
```

I get:

```
un  linux-image                               <none>                                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-2.6                           <none>                                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-2.6.24-23-server              <none>                                    (no description available)
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-28-server              2.6.32-28.55                              Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86_64
un  linux-image-2.6.32-31-server              <none>                                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-2.6.32-33-server              <none>                                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-2.6.32-34-server              <none>                                    (no description available)
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-37-server              2.6.32-37.81                              Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86_64
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-38-server              2.6.32-38.83                              Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86_64
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-41-server              2.6.32-41.94                              Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86_64
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-42-server              2.6.32-42.95                              Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86_64
in  linux-image-2.6.32-43-server              <none>                                    (no description available)
iU  linux-image-server                        2.6.32.43.50                              Linux kernel image on Server Equipment.
```

And

```
uname -r
```

Prints: "2.6.32-28-server"

I don't know how it got like this, but I think it might be from a script that last server admin had run to automatically delete old kernels.

Anyways, if I reinstall *-image-2.6.32-31, should it automatically run off of it after a reboot? Or is there another/simpler way to get to the latest version without reinstalling the purged kernels? This is a live server, and I'd don't want to go guessing and checking  on this one.

FYI, this whole problem stems from the fact that the hosting company of this server set up to boot partition to only be 80M and it's currently maxed out.

Comment: You might just need to run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I ran that and rebooted, but I'm still on *2.6.32-28. Also, I think that update-grub is run automatically by apt-get when removing (and I think upgrading, too) kernels.

Comment: It should, but I've had it either not run or fail and ended up using older kernels without realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your /boot mountpoint is not the one that GRUB points to.
Try to mount /boot partition to some temporary mountpoint such as /media/boot and see if it has the same files as /boot.

if it's true, one thing you can do is to mount boot partition to /boot (put it in /etc/fstab) but stay careful because any mistake can cause your computer be unbootable.

Another option is to run grub-install so GRUB code in MBR (Stage 1) will point to your current /boot ("/" mountpoint).

Another thing you mentioned, you might have problem with 80MB partition. you have to make sure you have kind of maximum of 2 kernel versions.

Read about those things before.

Comment: Thanks idgar, I'll read up on your suggestions and post back.